# How can I get it when I have count as count?

Tags: php, mariadb

I want to know the total counter
There are a total of 15 cc_cates.
I want to find the whole value with a single query.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT distinct cc_cate,
                  count(cc_cate)as count
             FROM cc_text
             WHERE id='aaaa'
             group by cc_cate
             order by cc_cate desc"
      ) or die("cate");
```

```
        for ($i = 0; $t = mysqli_fetch_array($result); $i++) {    
            if ($i == $t['count']) $last = "colspan=7"; 
            echo "$i == $t[count] ,";
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? Everything looks good from your ouput

Comment: it changes because you are doing a `GROUP BY cc_cate`. So you have the count for every cc_cate. To have a better understanding of what happens, change your echo to `echo "i = $i  | cc_cate = ".$t['cc_cate']." | count = ".$t['count'] ;`

Comment: Get some help in explaining your problem precisely.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: The same goes for vandalizing people's answers, don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

Still not totally clear, but following what you specified in the comments, I guess one of those 2 answers should be what you are looking for:

```
// if you just want the number of categories

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(distinct cc_cate) as cnt_cat FROM cc_text WHERE id='aaaa'") or die("cate");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "Number of categories = ". $row['cnt_cat'];


// if you want to list all categories and count them all 

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT distinct cc_cate FROM cc_text WHERE id='aaaa'") or die("cate");
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $i++;
    echo "Category $i = ". $row['cc_cate'];
}
echo "Total categories = $i";
```